# Fortify alchemy/fortify enchant stacking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to enchant a set of Fortify Alchemy equipment so that it allows you to create a more potent Fortify Enchanting potion than using the potion to recreate a more powerful set of alchemy equipment?
Can you repeat this to continually increase the power of the enchanting potion?
Has anyone tried this?
What kind of increase was seen between alchemy sets?

Comment: If the game scales then what is the point of super hard equipment if everything gets harder to match?

Comment: @Kort Pleco To the best of my knowledge the game scales the difficulty based on your level, not your equipment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unlike in Oblivion, you *can* stack skills over 100 with a combination of enchanting and alchemy.

You can easily wind up with something like this:
[image]

**There's not enough recursion** within the enchanting / alchemy skills to increase arbitrarily high, but you can definitely get some pretty nuts items regardless.

Comment: What do you mean by "not enough recursion"? From the process outlined in the question, it seems like this could go on forever. What prevents it?

Comment: @StrixVaria - I mean the amount of +bonus enchanting skill you get by wearing loads of +enchantment is not enough to allow you to enchant a *higher* amount of +enchantment. (As Mr. November mentions in his answer)

Comment: @Raven I thought the idea was to create a potion to give +enchant and then using your new +enchant skill to create a +alchemy armor. The you use your +alchemy armor and create a ++enchant potion. While under the effect of the ++enchant potion you create a set of ++alchemy armor...repeat as necessary.

Comment: I can understand the limit with the recursion issue... but just curious... how many sets did it take to get an enchanting potion that would allow you to create something like in your image?

Comment: @Goblinlord Dunno - I found it on Reddit :P

Comment: @Bravo840 that's *exactly the idea*. The problem is that after your ++enchant potion, you can't make it to +++enchant potions and +++alchemy armor (they don't scale fast enough)

Comment: Found much more detailed information on the process ^_^.  Here is a nice guide for it:
http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1266212-2469-armor-3199-damage-using-smithing-alchemy-enchanting-only-31-perks/

Comment: Also, a note on this... from what I have been doing in game... I honestly think that an item like in the image would be impossible without cheating using console commands.  The max you can make your potions would be 32% which with them and maxed enchanting/perks you end up with enchantments that reduce the cost of spells by 33%.  This is the enchant that does not increase Magika regen.  This means that even with Alchemy and Enchanting maxed you would still require 3 pieces to reduce the casting cost of 1 school of magic to 0 casting cost (one of those pieces being armor for that last 1%).

Answer (score 7):

This has been tried, and it flattens out at around 30%.

Answer (score 1):

the trick here is not to simply use enchanting to up alchemy to up enchanting etc. so u have a very good enchantment on your items, but to get an overpowered smithing enchantment on your items so you can then smith your items up waaaaaay beyond legendary aswell

Answer (score 0):

I did the smithing/potion trick with armor and weapons. So a 130% boost over my 100 smithing. 2 pieces of armor at 20% each, ring and necklace at 20% each and 50% boost potion. Then enchanted necklace, ring, and armor to boost stamina health magician regen, bow and one handed damage. So 120% damge up with bow or sword depending on which set of ring/amulet i equipped. I could go higher with alchemy custom potions but don't feel like it.

So results without alchemy boost: Smith/enchant 100, Heavy armor 100, one handed 100, and bow 70. Daedric short sword; 268 damage. 1-2 hits on adept in standard combat. Daedric bow; 300 damage. 1-2 hits kills Draugr death lords on adept with sneak attack. Regular dragons go down in 1-5 slashes, ancient in 5-15. Daedric armor with shield equipped yields 1500+ armor rating.  Can you say game breaking?

Comment: You do know there is armor cap just below 600, right?

Comment: @StupidOne Could you provide a source for that armor cap please?

Comment: @Fambida [uesp.net](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Guild_Master's_Armor#Guild_Master.27s_Armor). Both physical and magic DMG reduction is capped at 80%.

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Armor#Armor_Cap more on the armor cap.