# Are Alchemy and Enchanting broken in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fortify alchemy/fortify enchant stacking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/fortify-alchemy-fortify-enchant-stacking)

I was wondering whether you could use Alchemy to do this:

1. Make a potion to Fortify Making potions
2. Drink said potion and make a superior Fortify making potions.
3. Repeat until Fortify making potions is ridiculously high.
4. make a Fortify enchanting items potion(which will be buffed from your potion making potions).
5. make Fortify making potions enchantments on your items
6. congratulations, you just broke the game!

These methods, though i havent actually tried them out, can make you have a very highly increased enchantment bonus, which can of course give you all sorts of insane enchantments.

Was this maybe an oversight in Skyrim?

Comment: Whether or not being able to min/max your character to insane power levels in a strictly single player game is 'broken' or not is more of a philosophical discussion I think :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a Fortify Alchemy potion, therefor the method you describes doesn't work.

There is however a Fortify Enchanting potion, which, in turn, allows you to create Fortify Alchemy enchantment. you can read about it in another question: [Fortify alchemy/fortify enchant stacking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/fortify-alchemy-fortify-enchant-stacking)