# Why can I get more enchantment on steel armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The enchantment on my steel armor compared to my daedric armor is about 17,5% more powerful? Is there a penalty on the daedric armor? I can see the improvement on 2-3 armor pieces. I've 100 entchantment skill and the entchanment is carry weight and fortify one-handed.  I enchanted them with a long period of time in between so maybe I just confuse some values.

EDiT: I think this a glitch!!!! I've verified it. When I select an item and then the enchantement the system proposed a 17,5% higher enchantment percentage. Then when I must choose a gem to fuel the weapon I select my black star filled with a grand soul worth 1000g. Until now everthing is fine. But when I select for example a Grand Soul Gem filled with a grand soul worth only 500g then I get my expected lower entchantment percentage. When I change back to the black star it doesn't show me the higher entchantment percentage it shows me before the glitch? I can select the glitch again and select a grand soul or any other gem and back but the enchantment percentage remains about 17,5% under the first value? Hence when I craft the item I get only the maximum fuel of a grand soul gem filled with a grand soul even when my current selection is higher? What do you think? Do you can fix it? I've version 1.3.10 of the game.

Comment: Which enchantment?  What is your enchanting level? When did you enchant each item?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: I've 100 entchantment skill and the entchament is carry weight and fortify one-handed. I enchanted them shortly after I've bought my new home.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: It's a glitch!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Downvoters: Why downvote?

Answer (score 5):

1. Weaker soul in a large gem. It's easy to mistake Grand Soul Gem (Great) for Grand Soul Gem (Grand).
2. Obviously, any improvements to your Enchanting skill or new Enchanting perks will affect this.
3. Do you have any magic effects currently active? You can't enchant a +enchant%, but you could have a potion that will affect this.
4. Do you have a +restoration buff? All "Fortify X" effects are considered Restoration. Thus, a boost to your restoration will make a +enchant potion more effective than without the resto buff.
5. Do you have any negative effects when you do the daedric? Aside from the obvious, I think a debuff to resto would also hamper +enchant stuff you might be using.

The material doesn't make a lick of difference. Unlike Morrowind, the item receiving the enchantment has no bearing on the magnitude of the enchantment.

Comment: It's a glitch!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, enchantment strength is not influenced by the material of the item you are enchanting.

Are you sure that both souls used were the same strength? Note that soul gems can be filled with smaller souls than their maximum capacity, e.g. if you kill a skeever and all you have is an empty Grand Soul Gem, your Grand Soul Gem will be filled with a petty soul.

Comment: That's a good point maybe I'm confusing The Black Star with Grand Soul Gem but I'm pretty sure I use always Grand Soul filled with Grand Soul. I've this problem on 2 items the chance that I've picked a petty soul is then divided by half i.e. 50:50.

Comment: @least_signifcat_bit: It's a glitch!!!!!!