# is the restoration loop/glitch patched

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried it and I can't get higher then 63%, does someone know?

This is in skyrim with update 1.9 (I think), or at least the newest unofficial update (Version 1.9.32.0.8).

Comment: Could you provide more information about the glitch to give a little more context to this?

Comment: i believe he is talking about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG7uO5R-wds&feature=youtu.be @Krjax

Comment: For the sake of the people in the future, could somebody edit the 'newest unofficial update' into an actual version number?

Comment: just added it. @Ids

Comment: @Krjax The one talked about here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/fortify-alchemy-fortify-enchant-stacking?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes... This was patched out in 1.9. You can still get a pretty high one handed attack buff around 150% and such by doing some work but its no longer an infinite loop.

Comment: do you have a source for that? http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch this does not mention it being patched, unless i'm just blind and don't see it

Comment: @Dragonrage the USEp doesn't mention it, but it's still Patched.

Comment: It may have been fixed(i.e. doesn't work anymore) in the unofficial patch(mod) on PC, but it can still be done in the latest official patch(1.9x). I know because I've done it in the Legendary Edition of the Game(Patch 1.9, all DLC on PC with zero mods installed). The restoration potion glitch is alive and well(without the unofficial patch). The OP probably did something wrong during the loop process.

Comment: @Jtenorj3 You were able to get the 60k+ values of it? You can still Boost your stuff with this setup to reach the max points but it capped out and was not able to be continually done.